# Is this part (given picture) an EM relay, relay-controller, snubber?

Tags: relay, identification, solid-state-relay, snubber

Here is a rather bad (low resolution, grainy) picture of a circuit board that claims to be a 2-channel 315MHz ASK/OOK type remote controlled relay set. I can identify the relays, but not the big blue boxy thing behind them (see picture, with red-arrow).

[image]

Can someone help identify what it is ?

Also, is that white thingy labelled "Carli" part of this blue part, or separate ?

Comment: The yellow part is a separate component. It's a class X capacitor manufactured by Carli Electronics http://www.carli-cap.com.tw

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The blue part is a transformer (should be reasonably heavy). The "Carli" labeled part is probably a capacitor.

[image]

http://uk.farnell.com/block/vb1-5-2-9/transformer-1-5va-2-x-9v/dp/1131629

Comment: Thanks @Armandas. I do not have the board with me, so couldn't confirm whether it is heavy.

Answer (score 5):

Blue device is probably an iron core transformer.
 A better photo would allow website to be read.

That's probably a mains cord entering at top right.

Yellowish Carli components is probably an X filter cap - MAY be a line filter but probably not.

Bottom right - 4 diodes are probably bridge rectifier for power supply.

Picture is truncated but object at bottom left is probably an ASK/OOK or similar RF module - probably Rx/Tx
 Silver button thing may be a SAW filter / oscillator.

Black cubes are relays.

So, yes, it could be what it claims to be.

A better photo would help. - object at lower left is key to RF aspects.

**Guesstimated objects:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Russell, for the comprehensive answer and labelled pic. It so happens that this is first time I am seeing an encapsulated PCB-mount transformer! The IC labelled "???" is very likely to be the RF decoder IC. It is indeed a SAW resonator based 315MHz OOK module (as per specs). Any idea if the "yellow" spring-type terminal block is for the AC power (fed to Relays) ? Seem a trifle too small (& possibly under-spec'd) for mains power, no ? I'd have expected the AC connectors to be the larger screw-type ones.